# Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit results in 32-bit OS

Tags: 64-bit

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on my Dell 8500-XPS.  This was a side-by-side install with Windows 7 64-bit.  My system has 16 gig RAM.  When I check my Ubuntu system settings - details, it says my OS type is 32-bit.  What happened?

Output of `uname -a`:

```
3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `uname -m` is `i686`

Comment: could you paste the output of `uname -a` or `uname -m`?

Comment: Output of uname -a: 3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Output of uname -m: i686

Comment: How did you infer you installed 64-bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `uname -a`, it was clearly shown that you had installed Ubuntu 32 bit.

```
3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Yes, checking the install CD that is clear as well.  I'm quite certain I selected the 64-bit version when I burned the CD.  I will try again.

Comment: Please open the files in that installation cd.If there is any EFI folder on that, it's sure that the cd contains 64 bit Ubuntu.If not, then it is 32 bit.